# Default Minecraft resource pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As a hilarious April Fools joke, it appears the default Minecraft resource pack has had all the sounds replaced with the [Element Animation resource pack](http://www.elementanimation.com/resourcepack/). Is there any way to get the regular sounds back? I've searched for the default resource pack with no success.

Comment: **Endorsed by Dinnerbone!** (On topic) There's a way to get it back, wait until tomorrow.

Comment: **sigh** I guess so.

Comment: This is pretty annoying after the first 10 minutes.

Comment: Maybe changing to a different version would work?

Comment: People are all upset about this and Guild Wars 2's April Fools additions.  It's just a single day people, lighten up and have some fun!

Comment: Ohhhhhh I thought this was a glitch xD I had the TEARSP and I thought it was glitching into the game xD

Comment: @RichardA, maybe post this as an answer? It appears to be the "official" solution.

Comment: Will do, hold on.

Comment: For the record, here's [the Mojang bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-52310) on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to fix this (which it did) was to wait until the next day.

Disclaimer:
This joke was endorsed by Dinnerbone and Element Animation is (not) sorry.